# User cannot star/stop or SSM specified instance even after IAM policies are set right

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, group-policy

So in my case, a few users are assigned to an IAM group. This group allows them to start/stop instance, I am mainly focusing on getting them to SSM in that instance(which is also allowed in that IAM group).
I have confirmed through Policy stimulator that the user and policy have access to SSM and start/stop designated instances(using tags to select instances).
MFA=true is also included in policy and users are using MFA to login so that is sorted as well.

But for some reason, users are not able to start/stop or SSM in instances.

Any suggestion?

Comment: "But for some reason, users are not able to start/stop or SSM in instances." - is not specific. What do you mean? Any errors? How the users are doing this exactly? How to reproduce the issue? What are the exact IAM group permissions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is being RESOLVED.
In my case, the issue was latency because the clients were located in Netherland and Mumbai, and servers they were trying to access were located in US-East-1 and ap-southeast-2, for some reason in AWS console the connect button in Session Manager was not clickable.
A simple refresh once you reach that page fixed it.

(To check your internet speed with foreign servers, you get the option in internet speed test website to change your server location.)